# iOS disable oneTimeCode suggestion on a random place

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

Any idea of how I could disable 'From Messages suggestions'? I have not set

```
textfield.textContentType = UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode
```

but still, the suggestion from the previous login page shows up here which is totally irrelevant. Help would be appreciated.

[image]